# File.delete in cache doesnt work Android

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using this code to delete a file and download a picture to replace it, but the bool returned by delete is true but it doesn't show the new downloaded picture when I execute the code. It shows the old picture that was there before `delete()`

```
final File localFile = new File(getActivity().getCacheDir(), response + ".jpg");
                    localFile.delete();
            //if (ppSTAT == null) {
            if (true) {
                storageRef.child(response).getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
```

Comment: There is no code to show a picture.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the final keyword